# How we can add space between Tabs inside Tab bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have 6 Tabs and I want to group Tabs. Like first two Tabs together and then next two together and so on. So I need to add space after the 2nd Tab bar and 4th Tab bar. There is no direct property to space like this. I am customizing my Tabs so that they look like buttons.

Comment: Please provide some basic png or representation of what you achieve so far

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correct you want something like this?
[image: Tab Groups]

If you mean this, I added an extra tab between the groups. This tab is still technically tapped/clickable, however, I added a tabController, and used the onTap function of the TabBar to 'ignore' these extra tabs. If the tapped index is equal to the index of either 'gap tab' then the tab controller animated back to the previous tab which I am also keeping track of in an int.

Here is the code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final int numTabs = 8;
  final int initalIndex = 0;
  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // sets up the tabController
    tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: initalIndex,
      length: numTabs,
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: numTabs,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: const Text('Tab Example'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            onTap: (tappedIndex) {
              // if the tapped tab was either of the blank tabs
              if (tappedIndex == 2 || tappedIndex == 5) {
                // go back to the previous selected tab
                tabController.animateTo(currentIndex);
              } else {
                // update current tab if a selection one is 'real'
                currentIndex = tappedIndex;
              }
            },
            controller: tabController,
            tabs: const [
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'Group 1.1',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'Group 1.2',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              // empty tab
              Tab(
                child: Text(''),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'Group 2.1',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'Group 2.2',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              // empty tab
              Tab(
                child: Text(''),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'Group 3.1',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  'Group 3.2',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('Tabs'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is a bit of a clunky way to do this, but it may work well depending on what you are doing. Another option I thought of was why it even needs to be tabs. Could you make a custom widget that you place at the top of all the screens you want to show? You could even design the widget so it blends in with the app bar and looks like it's a part of it.